# One needs to be run from server and other runs itself, Why?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

There are two types of project given in samples of developers.arcgis.com

1. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/source-code.zip
2. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/get-started-mapview/index.html

When I try to run from the latter(No. 2), it gives me GET Err:404_file_not_found but the former(No. 1) runs smoothly. But No. 2 works only when it is in the server (in my case I'm using XAMPP).

Why does one need to be put in the server to work and the other not?

I'm new to this field but have decent knowledge in javascript.